# C++ find first item that occurs in all sub-vectors in a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

Given a vector containing `n` number of vectors, where `n` is unknown or can change, how can I find the first item that occurs in all the sub-vectors?
For example in this case:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { { 5,  7, 11, 12, 17, 23, 27 },
                                      { 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 23, 28 },
                                      { 1,  2,  5,  6, 12, 22, 23 },
                                      { 3,  7,  9, 12, 17, 23, 28 } };
```

the answer would be `12` (going from left to right for each of the 4 sub-vectors, `12` is the first number that appears in all sub-vectors).

I'm aware that in this case since there are only 4 sub-vectors I could hard-code a 4 layer loop to achieve this, but I need a solution that would work with the number of inner vectors not being known or changing.

**-- Edit 1 --**

Adding clarification for comment by @harold

The sub-vectors will not always be sorted, I just made it that way in this example so it's easier to look at.

If 2 numbers occur equally soon, then either number would be acceptable.  For example given:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { { 0, 1 },
                                      { 1, 0 } };
```

Then either `0` or `1` would be acceptable.

**-- Edit 2 --**

Adding clarification for comment by @PaulMcKenzie

If there is not identical item that is in all the sub-vectors, then it would be preferable to return some sort of error code, ex. `-9999`.  The only other possibility I could figure would be to cause an error to happen that the caller would then have to check for and know to handle.

**-- Edit 3 --**

Adding further clarification for comment by @PaulMcKenzie

The numbers within each sub-vector may not be unique.  For example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { { 1, 2, 3, 1 },
                                      { 2, 3, 4, 3 },
                                      { 1, 2, 1, 3 } };
```

All 3 sub-vectors have duplicates.  `2` and `3` are the only values that appear in all sub-vectors.  Considering values `2` and `3`, the earliest appearance of either is for value `2` index 0 in the 2nd sub-vector, so `2` would be the answer.

Comment: Are the subvectors always sorted? If not, then what should be the answer for something like { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 0 } }

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added clarifying info to the question above.

Comment: What if no numbers appears in all the sub-vectors?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, added clarifying info to the question above.

Comment: @cdahms Are the numbers all unique in each sub-vector?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Perhaps I don't understand what you're asking here.  For the example above, both 12 and 23 appear in each sub-vector, but since 12 appears first that would be the answer.

Comment: @cdahms `{ 1, 2, 3, 1}` -- The `1` appears twice in that single vector.  Your example shows each subvector having unique integers.  If all integers in each subvector are unique, then there are more ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Let's suppose that the values within each sub-vector may not be unique.

Comment: Added another clarifying example for duplicate values in sub-vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `std::unordered_map` along with a `std::unordered_set` to keep a count of the each integer, and return the first integer that reaches the number of sub-vectors.

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

size_t FirstNumberInAll(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vect)
{
    // The goal amount (number of sub vectors)
    size_t goal = vect.size();

    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> mapResults;
    std::unordered_set<int> setInt;

    for (auto& v : vect)
    {
        // Clear this at the start of each subvector processing
        setInt.clear();

        for (auto& v2 : v)
        {
            // If number is not already in the set
            // add it to the set, update the count and
            // check if the goal amount has been reached
            if ( !setInt.count(v2) )
            {
                ++mapResults[v2];
                if (mapResults[v2] == goal)
                    return v2;
                setInt.insert(v2);
            }
        }
    }
    return -9999;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { { 5,  7, 11, 12, 12, 12, 17, 23, 27 },
                                          { 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 23, 28 },
                                          { 1,  2,  5,  6, 12, 22, 23 },
                                          { 3,  7,  9, 12, 17, 23, 28 } };
    std::cout << FirstNumberInAll(vec);
}
```

Output:

```
12
```

Comment: In your version, the *"first"* item is according to the last vector ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vr5zo1sds) with `{{1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}`...

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach would be:

Construct a set of the first array.
Construct a set of the second array.
Construct a set which is an intersection of the first two sets.
Continue intersecting this set with sets constructed from the rest of the lists.
Iterate the vectors in an order which you consider ascending in respect to which item should be considered first.
The first encountered item which is present in the final intersected set is the result.

The complexity of this algorithm is easy to calculate and I think it cannot be easily improved.

Comment: There are some edge cases to consider, such as if there is only one subvector.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my relatively simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// function prototypes
int findFirstNumInAll(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vec);


int main()
{
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = { { 5,  7, 11, 12, 17, 23, 27 },
                                      { 8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 23, 28 },
                                      { 1,  2,  5,  6, 12, 22, 23 },
                                      { 3,  7,  9, 12, 17, 23, 28 } };
  
  int firstNumInAll = findFirstNumInAll(vec);
  
  std::cout << "\n" << "firstNumInAll = " << firstNumInAll << "\n\n";
  
  return 0;
}

int findFirstNumInAll(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vec)
{      
  std::vector<int> mergedVec = vec[0];
  std::vector<int> newMergedVec;
  for (unsigned int i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++)
  {
    // make a vector with the matching values from mergedVec and vec[i]
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < mergedVec.size(); j++)
    {
      for (unsigned int k = 0; k < vec[i].size(); k++)
      {
        if (mergedVec[j] == vec[i][k]) newMergedVec.push_back(mergedVec[j]);
      }
    }
    
    mergedVec = newMergedVec;
    newMergedVec.clear();
  }
  
  return mergedVec[0]; 
}
```

I think @PaulMcKenzie's solution above is much faster though, so I'll mark that as the answer.